# Why is LaTeX so messy?

Tags: discussion

I don't know where to fit this, because it is more a meta question about LaTeX so it does not fit on the main site, but it does also not fit here because meta should be about Tex.SE.
Anyways I feel, that meta always has a more informal character and therefore I ask here.
Now to the question:

I have the feeling that in LaTeX some functionality is like a kludge and that the original system was not designed for it (for example image display).

Is it just me or do you feel, that LaTeX is extremely messy, too?

Comment: As this is a question about LaTeX, not about TeX.SX, I'd say it belongs on TeX.SX, not on meta.

Comment: But it's pretty much not a real question, since it mainly calls for discussion.  We already have some similar questions on the site: [Why are there no alternatives to TeX, or, why is TeX still used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13370) and [Does TeX/LaTeX give a headstart with other programming languages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42734). There's plenty of good discussion there, so I don't think we need another one.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Ahh now I see that I searched for the wrong terms. Guess I was to narrow minded. Thank you for the pointers.